# How to use sqlite db and how to access mysql server database in android

Tags: android, webview

I am facing a problem to set the side of webpage loaded in android webview.

problem is when i load the login page of the website it gets fitted absolutely well in the webview but wen i click on the hyperlink for new signup then the next page(registration page) loads with 100% scale in the browser and shows horizontal and vertical scroll bars.
i want to fit this registration page according to device width.

how to do this please help me

tried almost all option available in stackoverflow n google

Also tell me how to access the SQL database(save and retrieve information from database) on android device which is operating the website

The code i used is :

Java file :

```
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
     String usrUrl = "http://" + txturl.getText().toString();
    mWebView.setInitialScale(30);
                //mWebView.setMinimumHeight(70);
                //mWebView.setMinimumWidth(30);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
                //mWebView.setWebViewClient(mWebView.set)
                //mWebView.setWebViewClient(clbk.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(mWebView, usrUrl));
                //mWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    mWebView.loadUrl(usrUrl);
```

In Manifest file :

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=240px" />
```

Comment: now i am able to fit the registration page in th phone screen but now i am having problem in zoom in and zoom out of the page.Then i have to access the SQL database from the application . Please help me how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
  webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
```

*EDIT*

You'll then need:

```
  webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

to alter the zoom afterwards

Comment: @Blundell : wat will this do in my application ?

Comment: It sets the default zoom when you appear on the page, so it'll zoom out.

Comment: page is zooming in well bt does not zoom out how to fit page again on devices screen after filling all the fields in the registration form ?

Comment: please tell me about using SQL db with android too

Comment: by using  webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); webpage zooms in and zooms out on double tap